# Firefox 4.06b IndexedDB support

Tags: javascript, firefox, html

Is it possible to access the IndexedDB API in Firefox 4.0b6?  If so, how?  window.indexedDB is not defined.  Currently working off of this example:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/category/indexeddb/as/complete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is difficult to find but it's called `moz_indexedDB` until the standard is further along: http://blog.dankantor.com/post/1018704095/ah-need-to-use-window-moz-indexeddb-instead-of

```
console.log("window.indexedDB: " + window.indexedDB);
window.indexedDB: undefined

console.log("window.moz_indexedDB: " + window.moz_indexedDB);
window.moz_indexedDB: [object IDBFactory]
```

Comment: I added a note to the documentation to try and clear this up more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB#Asynchronous_API

Answer (score 3):

Note that in Google Chrome, it's window.webkitIndexedDB.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out http://nparashuram.com/ttd/IndexedDB/index.html for specific examples on IE, FF and CHrome

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4b10: mozIndexedDb

Chrome 10: webkitIndexedDb